# Django - Can I add a calculated field that only exists for a particular sub-set or occurences of my model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Imagine that you have a model with some date-time fields that can be categorized depending on the date. You make an annotation for the model with different cases that assign a different 'status' depending on the calculation for the date-time fields:

```
#Models.py
class Status(models.TextChoices):
    status_1 = 'status_1'
    status_2 = 'status_2'
    status_3 = 'status_3'
    special_status = 'special_status'

class MyModel(models.Model):
    important_date_1 = models.DateField(null=True)
    important_date_2 = models.DateField(null=True)
    calculated_status = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=Status.choices, default=None, null=True, blank=False,)

objects = MyModelCustomManager()
```

And the manager with which to do the calculation as annotations:

```
# managers.py
class MyModelCustomManager(models.Manager): 
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset().annotate(**{
                    'status': Case(
                        When(**{'important_date_1' is foo, 'then':
                                Value(Status.status_1)}),
                        When(**{'important_date_2' is fii, 'then':
                                Value(Status.status_2)}),
                        When(**{'important_date_1' is foo AND 'importante_date_2' is whatever, 'then':
                                Value(Status.status_3)}),
                    # And so on and so on
                    )
              }
        )
        return queryset
```

Now, here's where it gets tricky. Only one of these sub-sets of occurrences on the model requires an ADDITIONAL CALCULATED FIELD that literally only exists for it, that looks something like this:

```
special_calculated_field = F('important_date_1') - F('importante_date_2') #Only for special_status
```

So, basically I want to make a calculated field with the condition that the model instance must belong to this specific status. I don't want to make it an annotation, because other instances of the model would always have this value set to Null or empty if it were a field or annotation and I feel like it would be a waste of a row in the database.

Is there way, for example to do this kind of query:

```
>>> my_model_instance = MyModel.objects.filter(status='special_status')
>>> my_model_instance.special_calculated_field
```

Thanks a lot in advance if anyone can chime in with some help.

Comment: Annotations are not a waste of a row in the database. They are just added in the result of the query that you get, so they don't do any changes to your database. But if you really want to do this, one way to do it is add properties to your model class

Comment: @bdbd Thank you for your response. I wanted to asked you if you could further explain to me how an annotation would work in this case? Which one would have the less possible impact on performance, considering we're working with 100k rows of data. Annotation or property in the model class?

Comment: I think it depends on how you use those 100k rows. If you need the calculated field on  a considerable amount of items, then I would go with annotations, otherwise model properties. But looking at your question again, I think you are already in the right direction, which is filter and then annotate.

Comment: @bdbd Thank you, feel free to drop a proper Answer in the question so that I can green mark you.